# Deduct from table column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I have this table below

```
ID  Amount User_id bal
1   900    2       0
2   800    3       0
3   500    2       0
```

Using PHP is it possible to get 1500 amount from the Amount column by adding two rows together and return what's left to the bal column

What I have done so far, MY SELECT query

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT amount FROM fund WHERE amount != 0  " );
```

This query returns all the available funds from the database.
The user request for 1500 but there's no 1500 available,so is there a way i can add two rows together to get the 1500

Comment: your question is not clear  .. you mean  adding two columns or two rows ?... show a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Can you please edit your question, its totally unclear. What you mean with "get 1500 of amount" ? What is this 1500? Please provide an example what you want. How should the result look like ?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything regarding calculations using PHP, so the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Yet most likely all the calculations can be done on SQL side which is preferred

Comment: @scaisEdge i actually mean two rows, also i have edit the question for more clarity

Comment: Added an answer  hope is useful

Comment: you need to sum the amount based on userid

Comment: I figured the best approach to this is by adding user_id to the query as @premi suggested. And this now work perfectly with ScaisEdge answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an accumulator  var and looping over the result.
eg:  (this is just a suggestion )

```
   $result =    $wpdb->get_results("SELECT amount FROM fund WHERE amount != 0  " );
   $myTotal  = 0;

    foreach ($result as $row) {

          $myTotal = $myTotal  + $row->amount;
          if ($myTotal>= 1500){
            break;
            }

    }

    echo $myTotal;
```